# Android Shake Code

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, shake

In my game I want the player to shake his phone, at any point during the game, and every shake will result in switching weapons.

Example: Player has knife, [shakes phone] and switches to a katana.

```
if (accelerometer.x >= 5 || accelerometer.x <= -5   || accelerometer.y >= 5 
   || accelerometer.y <= -5   || accelerometer.z >= 5 || accelerometer.z <= -5 )
   switchWep();
```

This works, the problem is **it has a side effect**.When the player shakes the phone sometimes it switches weapons twice. So I want to limit it so that if there is a big shake the game doesn't switch from weapon 0 to weapon 2.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put a simple time limitation on so you can't switch 2 times after each other. I think 1 sec - 500 msec would be sufficient to avoid a double switch.

**Edit**:
You could do this, but I'm not sure its the most optimal or lock safe way to do it.

```
protected void shake() {
    if(mAllowShake) {
        mAllowShake = false;

        // do shake

        Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                mAllowShake = true;
            }
        };

        handler.sendMessageDelayed(null, 500);  // time in milliseconds
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking that, but this is my first Android game. How do I tell it to wait?

Comment: That cause the app to crash on the phone.

Comment: @katrina Tryed to increase the interval?

Comment: It changes weapons once but then that's it, big crash.

Comment: Ok. Will try to increase to 2000.

Comment: Still crashes after the interval was changed to 2000.

Comment: @katrina can you give a log? It shouldn't crash asfaik

Answer (score 0):

You could try and change the .5 to a higher number.